# SPOnline Content Search webpart restricted by license?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I registered a demonstration tenant with a Business Essential account.

And I can't get Content Search to work.

- Is there a limitation?
- Can a Business Essential account be upgraded at all?

Comment: If you just need a demo tenant, and you work for a MS partner, you can request a 90-day demo at https://www.microsoftofficedemos.com with an E3 license.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer from the Office blog:

> The Content Search Web Part and Cross-site Publishing are available
>   for Office 365 for Enterprise plans. Specifically, these plans are: 
>   Office 365 Enterprise E3 and E4, Office 365 Education A3 and A4,
>   Office 365 government G3 and G4, and Office 365 Enterprise E3 for
>   Nonprofits.

[Search innovations for site and portal design in SharePoint Online](https://blogs.office.com/2013/10/29/search-innovations-for-site-and-portal-design-in-sharepoint-online/)

Comment: Does this reference to authoring or display? Does this mean they are not available for E1 (display)? The majority of planned tenant will be E1 licenses... If this does not work there is not much in it to switch to Google Apps..